# Verb for "unassigned deadline"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, vocabulary

I'm creating a task management system that provides team managers with an overview of the state of the tasks within a list of projects. This could sum up my intent:

```
Project A:
  7 open issues
  3 unassigned
  2 without a deadline

Project B:
  ...
```

The arrangement isn't exactly like this, and in some situations it appears as `7 open issues (2 without a deadline)`, which, due to its length, is causing an ugly break on the system's UI.

My question is whether there's a verb that would express the same intent, "without a deadline set". I noticed that `deadline` exists as a verb, but `undeadline` doesn't (and anyway doesn't sound very good). Any alternatives?

Edit: I'm thinking `w/o deadline`. It's visually distinguishable and meets the requirements. Any other recommendations are still welcome.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ELU.  I wonder if you have looked at the guidelines for participation.  The obvious answer to your question would be that, no, there is no word for what you are trying to say.  But please could you explain why you need it at all?  What does it mean to say that somebody has no deadline assigned to him/her?  Deadlines are assigned to actions, and actions are assigned to people.  Do you mean to say there might be someone who is not required to do anything in particular?  Or that s/he can choose when to do his/her assigned task(s) whenever s/he pleases?  Or what do you mean?

Comment: @Tuffy, thank you for your remarks. I didn't read the guidelines, but assumed those would be the same as stackoverflow... Apologies for that! Could you please take a look at my edit? I tried to make things clearer and give some context.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking `w/o deadline`.

This means that you *don't* actually need a different word—but are simply looking for ways to make the phrase shorter.

Given this, I think that **no deadline** would be simpler and take up even less space.

Comment: Yes, it is better to think ‘systems usage’ than ‘English Language Usage.  Or might there be some sort of principles of ‘systems (English) language usage’?

Comment: Yes, it's not necessarily a word, but I would still like to be consistent in the way that I phrase things. It seems more natural to me to read "2 w/o deadline" than "2 no deadline", and I value how it feels to read things within the system. Thank you for your suggestion, still !